# Vuejs v-bind v-for not populating into component template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

with html

```
  <div id="app">
    <gallery v-bind:links="['link1.jpg', 'link2.jpg']" />
  </div>
```

and component definition:

```
    Vue.component('gallery', {
      template: `
        <div v-if="!isReady">
        not ready
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          <image-grp v-for="src in links">
            <img v-bind:src="src">
          </image-grp>
        </div>
      `,
      data() {
        return {
          links: [],
          isReady: false
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.links = this.$el.getAttribute('links').split(',')
        this.isReady = true
        console.log(this.links);
      }
    });
```

I've managed to produce this html:

```
<div links="link1.jpg,link2.jpg">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="">
  </div>
</div>
```

The images are not showing up because of the empty `src`. The `src` should be filled in during the loop on `src in links`. The array `links` must be filled properly, cause the html shows the same number of `image-grp` elements as are in the `links` array.

I have tried a variety of ways to populate/bind/mustache the `src` into the dynamic `<img src="">` elements.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems with your code. It works.

But you should better make `links` to props, like this:

```
props: ['links']
```

Then, the other commented out lines are not needed.

### Playground

```js
Vue.component('gallery', {
  props: ['links'],
  template: `
    <div v-if="!isReady">
    not ready
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <image-grp v-for="src in links">
        <img v-bind:src="src">
      </image-grp>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      //links: [],
      isReady: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    //this.links = this.$el.getAttribute('links').split(',');
    this.isReady = true;
  }
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
   <gallery v-bind:links="['https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxnaT.jpg?s=256&g=1', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/50309120892edf29dcb2188bdabe3b08?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG']"></gallery>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: awesome.  can you point to something that explains (or explain) `better make links to props`? is it just a best practice? or is that why it wouldn't work until i changed `image-grp` to `div`?

Comment: OH...`props` then solves my issue with needing to split the csv!  _got it, ty_.

Comment: `props` are standard and it's simpler to do in your case. In general `props` offers much more then attributes, like `type checking` and `default values`. Check the docs about it.